# Confirm files exist in both locations, excluding directory structure

Tags: linux, backup, manjaro, synchronization

I have a folder of photographs (original directory).

I imported these photographs into Shotwell, which has copied the files into a directory structure based upon EXIF data (new directory/year/month/day).

I would like to double check that all files from the original directory have been correctly copied into the new directory structure. Specifically, I would like to generate a list of any files in the original folder that are not somewhere in the new folder (regardless of subdirectory). Ideally, checksum or some other content check is incorporated.

What is the best way to achieve this in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to store the md5sums of all files in one of the directory trees in a file, and then store the md5sums of all files in the other directory in another file.  Then check to see if there are any differences between them.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

find dir1/ -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort > dir1.md5
find dir2/ -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort > dir2.md5
comm -3 <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 dir1.md5) <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 dir2.md5)
```

This will output a list of md5sums that aren't in both files (see `man comm`, the `-3` option).  Any md5sums printed can be used to look up the filename(s) in the `dir1.md5` and `dir2.md5` files, e.g. with `grep` or `awk`.

BTW, in case it's not obvious, the .md5 files need to contain both the md5sums and the filenames, but we only want to compare the md5sums (the first "field" of the .md5 files) without the filenames (because the path/filenames will always be different between the two files even though the md5sums are the same), hence the process substitutions with `cut` as the arguments for `comm`.

Note: the md5sums from the files that are in dir2 but not in dir1 will be indented by a single tab.  That's useful for knowing which file (directory tree) a particular md5sum belongs to, so you can use that to extract the filenames for the first column from dir1.md5 and search filenames in the second column in dir2.md5.  Or just strip the leading whitespace with `sed`.